# ForEach row display

Tags: swift, swiftui

say I have an array and I can use ForEach view to iterate them and display each vertically or horizontally. But what if I want to show two items in a row from the array at a time and then continue to the next two items.

e.g.
[image]

Comment: LazyV or HGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Lazy*Grid`, e.g. [`LazyVGrid`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid).

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(1 ... 5, id: \.self) { number in
                Text(String(number))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]